# How to divide a page and put the text boxes adjacent to each other

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2015, winjs, apache-cordova

I am creating an Apache cordova application using Visual studio focusing on the windows tablet and iPads. For styling currently i m using Winjs. Here I am attaching an image where I need the last 4 text boxes adjacent to each other.
And I used span, div and what all I could but couldnt get to do so. Please Help!

[image: App screen]

Here is the HTML part which I have:-

```
 <script src="./winjs/js/base.min.js"></script>
<script src="./winjs/js/ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="nav_home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```
<div class="divContainer" style="vertical-align: top;">

    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <div class="win-h3">Sales Force</div>
        <hr class='styleHr' />
    </header>

    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">

        <h2 class="win-h2"> POS Details</h2>


        <div id="dv1">

            Name:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <input type="text" value="CORINNE" class="win-textbox" /><br />
            Address: &nbsp; <input type="text" value="Rue De Cambon" class="win-textbox" /><br />
            Zip code: &nbsp;<input type="text" value="77561" class="win-textbox" /> <br />
            Sales Rep:&nbsp;<input type="text" value="111 - Delphine Dupont" class="win-textbox" />
        </div>



        <div id="dv2">
            Name:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <input type="text" value="CORINNE" class="win-textbox" /><br />
            Address: &nbsp; <input type="text" value="Rue De Cambon" class="win-textbox" /><br />
            Zip code: &nbsp;<input type="text" value="77561" class="win-textbox" /> <br />
            Sales Rep:&nbsp;<input type="text" value="111 - Delphine Dupont" class="win-textbox" />

        </div>

        <br />

        <table class="table-fill">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">Contact Name</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Contact Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Josephine Brew</td>
                    <td class="text-left">056-987-321</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Ashley Rose</td>
                    <td class="text-left">056-123-744</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Brian Knight</td>
                    <td class="text-left">056-987-321</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Ingrid Withers</td>
                    <td class="text-left">056-963-852</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Eva Jones</td>
                    <td class="text-left">056-753-951</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>




    </section>
```

I also would like to know that how would I put graphic buttons at down of the page which will follow WinJs abilities. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<br/>` tag after the `<input>` tags in your html.

`<br/>` is a line break. This is almost definitely your problem.

Comment: I tried it but it puts the first 4 text boxes in a same line and other 4 in the next line. I actually want the first 4 in one side and other 4 adjacent to it .

Comment: then add the `float:left` property to your first div css and `float: right` to your second.

Comment: Now I tried this too. Still no change buddy! Is it because of the ` <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
` These 2 divs, I have included inside it.

Comment: Repost your question with a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), and under the CSS section of Stack Overflow.